# my Css3 animation not working on mozilla

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I tried adding -moz- but it doesnt wave.. it works on chrome but not on mozilla firefox
I don't know whats wrong with it.. and help would be appreciated.. I doesnt animate on mozilla firefox :(

here is the code

```
 <ul class="notes-dance">
<li>&#9833;</li>
<li>&#9834;</li>
<li>&#9835;</li>
<li>&#9834;</li>
<li>&#9835;</li>
<li>&#9836;</li>
<li>&#9833;</li>
<li>&#9835;</li>
<li>&#9836;</li>
<li>&#9833;</li>
</ul>
```

and the css code :

```
ul li {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    font-size: 2em;
    color: #ccc;
    text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 white, 0 1px 0 black;
}
.anim {
  -moz-animation: music 1s ease-in-out both infinite;
    -webkit-animation: music 1s ease-in-out both infinite;
  animation : music 1s ease-in-out both infinite;

}

@-webkit-keyframes music {
    0%,100% {
    -moz-transform: translate3d(0,-10px,0);
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,-10px,0);
    transform: translate3d(0,-10px,0);
    }
    50% {
    -moz-transform: translate3d(0,10px,0);
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,10px,0);
      transform: translate3d(0,10px,0);
    }
}

@-moz-keyframes music {
    0%,100% {

    transform: translate3d(0,-10px,0);
    }
    50% {

      transform: translate3d(0,10px,0);
    }
}


.notes-dance{
  left: 30%;
    right: 50px;
    top: 90%;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: Works for me http://jsfiddle.net/GCu2D/426/ . Are you sure you added the class 'anim' to ul?

Comment: Yes, it works for me too. Also, this is not related to Twitter-Bootstrap

Comment: Works fine in Firefox 33.1. Only the `webkit` prefix is required [Firefox has native support for CSS animation](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-animation) going back a long time.

Comment: the animation is not showing when I inspect element mozilla firefox but it there is animation in google

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use This One for **@-moz-keyframes**

```
@-moz-keyframes music {
    0% {-moz-transform: translate3d(0,-10px,0);}
    50% {-moz-transform: translate3d(0,10px,0);}
    100% {-moz-transform: translate3d(0,-10px,0);}
}
```

You added `@-moz-keyframes` with no `-moz-transform` !! and you added `-moz-transform` to `@-webkit-keyframes`

Comment: Firefox has supported transform without the -moz- prefix since version 16, it isn't needed anymore http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d

Answer (score 1):

As per http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-animation:

> @keyframes not supported in an inline or scoped stylesheet in Firefox (bug 830056)

Are you using it in an inline or scoped way? If so, there's your answer.

Comment: I'm using scoped way sir

Comment: Then the animation won't work. inline or scoped stylesheets don't work with @keyframes in Firefox. If you can switch to a <link> global stylesheet it could work?